# Veracode ASP.NET C# Response.Redirect Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config, veracode

This is not a question that I'm asking, but an answer that I'm giving for to a problem that had been plaqueing me for a few days.

We were tasked to build a simple static ASP.Net application with a sign-in to access the site.  We decided to go with Forms Authentication for this, and the site itself only contains about a dozen pages.  We were asked to use Veracode to address any security flaws, and kept coming up against a security threat around the Response.Redirect.  Veracode kept saying that we needed to evaluate against a whitelist of domains and try to button up this security flaw, but we found a simple solution for this with built in Forms Authentication.

For this solution, there are 2 things that you need.

First, the web.config.  On your  tag, make sure that you have the following attribute:

```
    <forms  enableCrossAppRedirects="false" ></forms>
```

This makes sure that any redirect link that is returned through the query string is a local redirect only.  It will not allow for any links outside of your site to be resolved.

Next, in the code behind of your login page, You will only need the following line of code:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false, "/");
```

This ensures that the redirect follows the rules that are setup in the web.config, and also sets the cookie for you.

Pre-compile your application again in Visual Studio, or use the plugin to upload and scan from there, and be amazed as it passes the validation.